# How to find the count of intersection of two sets in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel, let's you get two sets based on some filters. Say set1 is A1:A10 and set 2 is A20:A30.
How do you find the count of elements which are present in both sets. (count of intersection).

Sample example -
[image]

What's needed is the count of unique sids which are present in both Jan-23 and Feb-23 (intersection - 7 in this example (c,d,e,f,g,h,i)). Similary, will need common between Feb-23 and Mar-23 and so on..

Comment: By manual filters, or formula filters? Please update your question with at least a reproducible sample. Will you need one total result or a result per element?

Comment: Using formula filter.. one total result.. updated with an example

Comment: Is the month column text or date values (including/excluding different days if the month)?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a lambda in the name manager named `MONTHCOMPARE` with formula:

`=LAMBDA(sid,month,a,b,SUM(N(UNIQUE(FILTER(sid,month=a))=TOROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(sid,month=b))))))`

Then in your sheet write `=MONTHCOMPARE(A2:A25,B2:B25,"Jan-23","Feb-23")`

The arguments are:
Argument 1: SID range
Argument 2: Month range
Argument 3: Month name of month 1 to compare
Argument 4: Month name of month 2 to compare

(Formula used for testing `=LAMBDA(sid,month,a,b,SUM(N(UNIQUE(FILTER(sid,month=a))=TOROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(sid,month=b))))))(A2:A25,B2:B25,"Jan-23","Feb-23")`
)

Answer (score 1):

### Count of Intersection

**Formula in `F2`**

```
=LET(ldata,B$2:B$21,rdata,A$2:A$21,fval,D2,sval,E2,
    ff,FILTER(rdata,ldata=fval),
    sf,FILTER(rdata,ldata=sval),
COUNT(UNIQUE(XMATCH(ff,sf))))
```

**LAMBDA Formula**

```
=LAMBDA(ldata,rdata,fval,sval,LET(
    ff,FILTER(rdata,ldata=fval),
    sf,FILTER(rdata,ldata=sval),
COUNT(UNIQUE(XMATCH(ff,sf)))))
```

[image]

**LAMBDA Function**

```
=CountI(B$2:B$21,A$2:A$21,D2,E2)
```

**Related**

[image]

In `H2` ('forgot' `UNIQUE`)

```
=LET(ldata,B$2:B$21,rdata,A$2:A$21,fval,D2,sval,E2,
    ff,FILTER(rdata,ldata=fval),
    sf,FILTER(rdata,ldata=sval),
COUNT(XMATCH(ff,sf)))
```

In `I2`

```
=LET(ldata,B$2:B$21,rdata,A$2:A$21,fval,D2,sval,E2,
    ff,FILTER(rdata,ldata=fval),
    sf,FILTER(rdata,ldata=sval),
    m,XLOOKUP(ff,sf,sf,""),
result,HSTACK(TEXTJOIN(", ",,m),TEXTJOIN(", ",,ff),TEXTJOIN(", ",,sf)),
result)
```